# Discrete Mathematics Surjective injective bijective proof

Tags: functions

1. Prove that the following function f : R+ → R>2 is both injective and
   surjective and therefore, bijective.

$$f(x) = 2 + \sqrt{x}$$

2. Use the method of disproof by counterexample to show that function $g:
   Z \to Z$ with the following general formula is neither injective nor surjective: $g(n) = n^2 − 8$

Comment: The first statement is true taking f from R+ to R+ but I don't understand what "R> 2" means.

Comment: I think OP means $\mathbb{R}_{>2} = (2,\infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 2} = [2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to sketch out the argument/steps required to solve this problem fully. I leave it to you to write out the details.

To prove that $f$ is injective, start by assuming that $f(x) = f(y)$ for two $x,y \geq 0$. Written explicitly, this means that
$$
\sqrt{x} + 2 = \sqrt{y} + 2.
$$
Through simple manipulations, you can deduce that $x = y$. This means that $f$ is injective.

As for the surjectivity of $f$ fix $y \in [2,\infty)$. Our job is then to prove that there exists $x \geq 0$ such that $f(x) = y$. That is, we want $x \geq 0$ such that
$$
y = f(x) = \sqrt{x} + 2.
$$
Again, you can check that this $x$ exists. This would prove the surjectivity of $f$.

Now we look at 2. Consider the function
$$
g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, \quad g(n) := n^2 - 8.
$$
To prove that $g$ is not surjective, we must find $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(n) \neq m$ for *all* $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. (Hint: consider $m=0$). As for injectivity, it should be clear that $g(-1) = g(1)$.